# Solicitud a API de Nextcloud

Tags: python, api, get, nextcloud

Estoy intentando hacer una solicitud para ver la lista de archivos en NextCloud utilizando la biblioteca requests de python, pero al hacer la solicitud e imprimirla en consola me devuelve html, y necesito que me devuelva en formato json.
Este es el codigo

```
files_response = requests.request(
    'GET',
    'https://cloud.fullweb.uy/apps/files/files/141446?dir=/Nico',
    auth=(NEXTCLOUD_USER, NEXTCLOUD_PASSWORD),
    headers={'OCS-APIREQUEST': 'true'}
)
```

Me tira codigo 200 asi que la solicitud se realizo correctamente, no se si estoy escribiendo mal la carpeta o algo asi pero estoy trancado.